# How can I constrain a QuickCheck parameter to a list of non-empty Strings?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I have a property that takes a list of Strings:

`myProp :: [String] -> Bool`

I need to constrain the inputs that QuickCheck generates so that only non-empty strings are in the list.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You use [`forAll`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.7.6/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:forAll) together with [`listOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.7.6/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:listOf) (which generates lists) and [`listOf1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.7.6/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:listOf1) (which generates non-empty lists).

#### Examples

```
quickCheck $ forAll (listOf $ listOf1 arbitrary) $ myProp
```

```hs
-- more verbose alternative to make things clear
nonEmptyString :: Gen String
nonEmptyString = listOf1 arbitrary

quickCheck $ forAll (listOf nonEmptyString) $ myProp
```

Comment: Thanks!  My issue before was actually in my property

Answer (score 3):

Or, from first principles (no library functions):

```
quickCheck $ \ h t -> let {s :: String ; s = h : t } in length s > 0
```

here `s` runs through all non-empty values.

Answer (score 3):

```
import Test.QuickCheck.Modifiers (NonEmptyList (..))

myProp :: [NonEmptyList Char] -> Bool
myProp xs0 =
  let xs = map getNonEmpty xs0
  in ...
```

Comment: Sorry... I should have explained my edit. I just liked your approach a lot and figured the code should be fixed to do what the OP requested.

Comment: @dfeuer No problem. I didn't read the OP's question very carefully, and didn't understand your edit at first. Thanks for the fix.