# Haskell quickBatch: Testing ZipList Monoid at mconcat results in stack overflow

Tags: haskell

i've created orphaned instances for ZipList Semigroup and Monoid.  However, when I run the tests from quickBatch on monoid, at the mconcat test, there is a stack overflow error.  How do I resolve this error?  Why is there such an error?  Is it due to `pure mempty`, which I do not quite understand as I got this mostly from HaskellBook Chapter 17 Applicative section 17.8 ZipList Monoid?

```
zl :: ZipList (Sum Int)
zl = ZipList [1,1 :: Sum Int]
instance Semigroup a 
  => Semigroup (ZipList a) where
    (<>) = liftA2 (<>)
instance (Eq a, Monoid a)
  => Monoid (ZipList a) where
    mempty = pure mempty 
    mappend = (<>)
    mconcat as = 
      foldr mappend mempty as
main :: IO ()
main = do 
  quickBatch $ monoid zl
```

[image]

Comment: `mempty :: ZipList a` is an infinite list: I wonder if it is trying to do something like `mempty <> mempty` (though it seems odd it would try that for `mconcat` but not `mappend` itself).

Comment: @chepner thanks for the hint, but i'm still confused over the use of `pure mempty`, what's `mempty` supposed to be or do here?

Comment: For `ZipList`, `(<>)` simply builds a `ZipList` by using `(<>)` on corresponding elements of its two arguments. That is, `ZipList [a,b,c] <> ZipList [x, y ,z] == ZipList [a<>x, b<>y, c<>z]`. Since `mempty :: ZipList a` has to be able to combine with *any* `ZipList` value, it has to be an infinite list, so that `(<>)` never runs out of elements to pair with the other list. My assumption is that somehow `mconcat` is attempting to iterate over the "entire" value of `mempty`, leading to infinite recursion and a stack overflow, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: If you are asking about `mempty = pure mempty`, it just means that given `mempty :: a`, you call `pure` on it to get a `ZipList a`, and `pure :: a -> ZipList  a` creates an infinite list of `a`s.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for shining some light on this!  I'm now also looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50130388/ziplist-monoid-haskell, I'm hoping that I can use that with Arbitrary and quickBatch, such that the monoid mconcat problem can be resolved..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the error is due to `pure mempty`, but that doesn't mean `pure mempty` is wrong.  Let's look there first.

It helps a lot to look at the types involved in the definition `mempty = pure mempty`:

```hs
mempty :: ZipList a
mempty = (pure :: a -> ZipList a) (mempty :: a)
```

Basically, we're going to use the `pure` operation to create a `ZipList` out of the `mempty` of type `a`.  It helps from here to look at the [definition of `pure` for `ZipList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/src/Control.Applicative.html#line-132):

```hs
pure :: a -> ZipList a
pure x = ZipList (repeat x)
```

In total, `mempty` for `ZipList a` is going to be a `ZipList` containing the infinitely repeating list of `mempty` values of the underlying type `a`.

---

Back to this error you're getting.  When you try to run the test `monoid` over `ZipList (Sum Int)`, QuickCheck is going to test a sequence of properties.

- The first two check the left identity and right identity properties.  What these do is generate values of type `x :: ZipList (Sum Int)` and verify that `x <> mempty = mempty <> x = x`.
- The third checks that for any two values `x, y :: ZipList (Sum Int)`, we have that `x` mappend `y = x <> y`.
- The fourth checks that for any list of values `x :: [ZipList (Sum Int)]`, folding these with `mappend` is the same as `mconcat`ing them.

Before I continue, it's really important to note that when I say "for any value", I really mean that QuickCheck is using the `Arbitrary` instance of the said type to generate values of that type.  Furthermore, the `Arbitrary` instance for `ZipList a` is the same as the `Arbitrary` instance for `[a]` but then wrapped in `ZipList`.  Lastly, the `Arbitrary` instance for `[a]` will never produce an infinite list (because those will cause problems when you're checking for equality, like going into an infinite loop or overflowing the stack), so these "for any values" of type `ZipList (Sum Int)` will never be infinite either.

*Specifically, this means that QuickCheck will never arbitrarily generate the value `mempty :: ZipList a` because this is an infinite list.*

---

So why do the first 3 pass but the last one fails with a stack overflow?  In the first three tests, we never end up trying to compare an infinite list to an infinite list.  Let's see why not.

- In the first two tests, we're looking at `x <> mempty == x` and `mempty <> x == x`.  In both cases, `x` is one of our "arbitrary" values, which will never be infinite, so this equality will never go into an infinite loop.
- In the third test, we're generating two finite ZipLists `x` and `y` and `mappend`ing them together.  Nothing about this will be infinite.
- In the third case, we're generating a list of ZipLists and `mconcat`enating the list.  But, what happens if the list is empty?  Well, `mconcat [] = mempty`, and folding an empty list produces `mempty`.  This means, if the empty list is generated as the arbitrary input (which is perfectly possible), then the test will try to confirm that an infinite list is equal to another infinite list, which will always result in a stack overflow or black hole.

---

How can you fix this?  I can come up with two methods:

1. You can define your own version of `EqProp` for `ZipList` so that it only compares equality on some finite prefix of the list.  This would likely involve making a newtype wrapper (perhaps `newtype MonZipList a = MonZipList (ZipList a)`), deriving a bunch of instances, and then writing an `EqProp` one by hand.  This will probably work but is a little inelegant.
2. You can write your own version of `monoid` that uses a different version of the fourth test.  For instance, if you restrict it so that the test only uses non-empty lists, then you won't have any problem.  To do this, you should start by looking at [the definition of the `monoid` property tests](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/checkers-0.5.6/docs/src/Test.QuickCheck.Classes.html#monoid).  Notice that it currently defines the "mconcat" property as `property mconcatP` where

```hs
mconcatP :: [a] -> Property
mconcatP as = mconcat as =-= foldr mappend mempty as
```

Using QuickCheck's own `NonEmptyList` class, you can rewrite this for your purposes as:

```hs
mconcatP :: NonEmptyList a -> Property
mconcatP (NonEmptyList as) = mconcat as =-= foldr mappend mempty as
```

Obviously, this is a slightly weaker condition, but at least it's one that won't hang.

Comment: Thanks!  Could you elaborate more about your solutions?  For your first solution, how do I create a quickBatch test for a finite prefix of ZipList?

Comment: For your second solution, I've tried to restrict the mconcat test by defining in `instance (Eq a, Monoid a) => Monoid (ZipList a)`, `mconcat as = if as /= [] then foldr mappend mempty as else ZipList []`, but it didn't work because the mconcat test fails at first try..

Comment: I updated the question with some suggestions about how to make the changes I suggested.  As for your alternate `moncat` definition, this will fail the test because the test still expects the result of `mconcat []` to be an infinite list.  True, it's not going into an infinite loop any more, but that's because it's now obvious that `[]` is not an infinite list.

Comment: Ok, I've tried QuickCheck's NonEmptyList, but if I use `mconcatP (NonEmptyList as) = ..`, I get an error `Not in scope: data constructor ‘NonEmptyList’`, and if I use `mconcatP (nonEmptyList as) = ..` or `mconcatP (getNonEmpty as) = ..`, I get `Parse error in pattern` ..

Comment: I got the idea of using `getNonEmpty` from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329303/how-can-i-constrain-a-quickcheck-parameter-to-a-list-of-non-empty-strings

Comment: I also created `nonEmptyList = listOf1 (arbitrary :: Gen [Int])`, but I realised that it doesn't work with `mconcatP (nonEmptyList as) = ..`, is there something wrong with the way I'm using NonEmptyList?

Comment: Perhaps you need to import it?  `import Test.QuickCheck (NonEmptyList(..))`

Comment: I've already done that.. don't worry, if you do not have the answer, I'll post another question about this. I'm also having problems understanding Ap, I've posted my questions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65763728/haskell-quickbatch-ap-applicative-monoid. Maybe you can take a look? You may know more than enough to answer my questions because my understanding of Ap is quite poor..

Answer (score 0):

As an aside, this definition of `Monoid` for `ZipList` is inconsistent with the definition of `Alternative` for `ZipList`.

I would propose instead:

```
instance Semigroup a => Semigroup (ZipList a) where
ZipList [] <> ZipList ys = ZipList ys
ZipList xs <> ZipList [] = ZipList xs
ZipList (x:xs) <> ZipList (y:ys) = ZipList (x <> y : getZipList (ZipList xs <> ZipList ys))

instance Semigroup a => Monoid (ZipList a) where
mempty = ZipList []
```

There is no formal requirement that `empty` in an `Alternative` instance be the same as `mempty` in `Monoid`, but without an extremely good reason to do so I wouldn't choose otherwise.