# Haskell monoid quickBatch tests: How to change mconcatP?

Tags: haskell

Based on the suggestion at [Haskell quickBatch: Testing ZipList Monoid at mconcat results in stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65716919/haskell-quickbatch-testing-ziplist-monoid-at-mconcat-results-in-stack-overflow#65764731),

and some solutions at
[How can I constrain a QuickCheck parameter to a list of non-empty Strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329303/how-can-i-constrain-a-quickcheck-parameter-to-a-list-of-non-empty-strings),

I've not been able to make this code workable:

```
instance Semigroup a 
  => Semigroup (ZipList a) where
    (<>) = liftA2 (<>)
instance Monoid a
  => Monoid (ZipList a) where
    mempty = pure mempty 
    mappend = liftA2 mappend
    mconcat as = 
      foldr mappend mempty as
mconcatP :: NonEmptyList a -> Property
mconcatP (nonEmptyList as) = mconcat as =-= 
  foldr mappend mempty as
nonEmptyList :: Gen [[Int]]
nonEmptyList = listOf1 (arbitrary :: Gen [Int])

zl :: ZipList (Sum Int)
zl = ZipList [1,1 :: Sum Int]
main :: IO ()
main = do 
  quickBatch $ monoid zl
```

I've also tried these:

```
import Test.QuickCheck 
  (NonEmptyList (..))
import Test.QuickCheck.Modifiers
  (NonEmptyList (..))
```

ghci will throw the error:

```
Parse error in pattern: nonEmptyList
mconcatP (nonEmptyList as) = mconcat as =-=
```

I've also tried:

```
mconcatP (NonEmptyList as) = mconcat as =-=
```

The error thrown is:

```
Not in scope: data constructor ‘NonEmptyList’
Perhaps you meant variable ‘nonEmptyList’
```

I've also tried:

```
mconcatP :: (EqProp b, Monoid b) => 
  NonEmptyList b -> Property
mconcatP (getNonEmpty -> as) = 
  mconcat as =-= 
  foldr mappend mempty as
```

This enabled the running of the monoid tests, but the mconcat test still hang.

I've also tried:

```
mconcatP :: (EqProp b, Monoid b) => 
  NonEmptyList b -> Property
mconcatP (NonEmpty as) = mconcat as =-= 
  foldr mappend mempty as
```

This also enabled the running of the monoid tests, but the mconcat test still hang.

I've checked using `:i NonEmptyList`, the outcome:

```
newtype NonEmptyList a = NonEmpty {getNonEmpty :: [a]}
    -- Defined in ‘Test.QuickCheck.Modifiers’
instance Eq a => Eq (NonEmptyList a)
  -- Defined in ‘Test.QuickCheck.Modifiers’
instance Functor NonEmptyList
  -- Defined in ‘Test.QuickCheck.Modifiers’
instance Ord a => Ord (NonEmptyList a)
  -- Defined in ‘Test.QuickCheck.Modifiers’
instance Show a => Show (NonEmptyList a)
  -- Defined in ‘Test.QuickCheck.Modifiers’
instance Read a => Read (NonEmptyList a)
  -- Defined in ‘Test.QuickCheck.Modifiers’
instance Arbitrary a => Arbitrary (NonEmptyList a)
  -- Defined in ‘Test.QuickCheck.Modifiers’
```

My Cabal file is very simple:

```
-- testing.cabal
name: testing
version: 0.1.0.0
license-file: LICENSE
author: Max
maintainer: maxloo
build-type: Simple
cabal-version: >=1.10

library
  exposed-modules: Testing
  ghc-options: -Wall -fwarn-tabs
  build-depends: base >=4.7 && <5
      , hspec
      , QuickCheck
      , checkers
  hs-source-dirs: .
  default-language: Haskell2010
```

Why does it not work?  How do I change mconcatP's code to enable the mconcat test from the 5 quickBatch monoid tests to run without stack overflow?

Comment: Oh, uhh, this isn't going to make `monoid zl` work.  That function uses its own version of `monoidP` internally, and you can't change that without changing the function itself.  What you _can_ do is define your own version of `monoid`.  Just copy the code into your project (perhaps renaming it, e.g., `monoidNonEmpty`), and redefine `monoidP` internal to this new version.

Comment: Sorry, I'm missing something here.  Do I have to create a new file monoidNonEmpty.hs?  My current code is in the file Testing.hs.  So, I'll have to include `import monoidNonEmpty` in my Testing.hs?  How do I redefine monoidP?  Do I need to update my Cabal file?

Comment: I'm not sure what wasn't clear about my statement.  Literally: copy the code of `monoid` into your test module.  Change the line that defines `monoidP` to your version of `monoidP`.  Change your `quickBatch` line to call your new version of `monoid`.  I mean, if you want, you can put this new version of `monoid` into a separate module (then, of course, you'd have to update your cabal file—also, module names must be capitalized), but that's up to you.

Comment: The problem I face is that there is no `monoidP` in `Data.Monoid`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html..  There is also no `monoidP` in `Test.QuickCheck.Checkers`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/checkers-0.5.6/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Checkers.html..  And if I am to copy the actual `Monoid` source code, will it start from https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#Monoid?  Where should it end?  There's quite a lot of code there..

Comment: I'm talking about the function `monoid`: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/checkers-0.5.6/docs/src/Test.QuickCheck.Classes.html#monoid.  This is the function you're calling, and this is what you need to copy and modify.  Notice that it _internally_ defines a function `monoidP`—that is what you need to change in your local version.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but there's no `monoidP`, only `mconcatP`, and the method you propose threw up a lot of errors centred around the context: `(Monoid a, Show a, Arbitrary a, EqProp a)`, namely Monoid, Arbitrary and EqProp.  I copied from the line `monoid :: forall a. ..` until the line `monoidSemigroupP x y ..`, and included my own code for `mconcatP`.  I also removed the `#if` code.  Am I right in doing these?

Comment: You're right.  It's called `mconcatP`.  Yes, you can remove the lines that start with `#`, but you should keep in the `mappend` test and the definition of `monoidSemigroupP `.  The type for `mconcatP` should be `NonEmptyList a -> Property`.  You may need to enable `ScopedTypeVariables` by adding `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}` to the top of your file so that the `a` type properly scopes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```hs
functionName pat1 = result
```

then GHC expects that `pat1` is a pattern.  Patterns are very specific things that need to either be identifier names that get bound to inputs or constructors that get matched to data type shapes (and also the extensions `ViewPatterns` and `PatternSynonyms` that extend this further).

So, when you write

```hs
mconcatP (nonEmptyList as) = as
```

then GHC becomes very confused.  `nonEmptyList` is not a constructor names (constructors always start uppercase), and because it's in parentheses with another identifier, it's not a lone identifier to bind input.  Therefore, GHC concludes rightly that this isn't a valid pattern.

What you're looking for is:

```hs
mconcatP (NonEmpty as) = ...
```

---

There are a few alternatives you could write too!  For instance, with `ViewPatterns` enabled, you could write:

```hs
mconcatP (getNonEmptyList -> as) = ...
```

This is a "view pattern", which tells GHC to take the argument, apply the function `getNonEmptyList` to it, and then bind the result to the identifier `as`.

Since this is QuickCheck, you can also use [`forAll`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html#v:forAll), which allows you to supply a generator and a function over the generated value to produce a property.  It would look like this:

```hs
mconcatP = forAll nonEmptyList $ \as -> ...
```

Comment: Upon double checking, it looks like the constructor for `NonEmptyList` is just `NonEmpty`.  I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my post. I've also tried `mconcatP (NonEmptyList as)`, but an error was thrown.  I've also tried `mconcatP (getNonEmpty -> as)` because an error was thrown when I use getNonEmptyList, but the outcome was stack overflow at the mconcat test again.